# Python pandas only reads days when comparing dates from csv

Tags: python, pandas

so let's say this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_table('file_name', sep=';')
pd.Timestamp("today").strftime(%d.%m.%y)
df = df[(df['column1'] < today)]
df
```

Here's the table from the csv file:

```
Column 1
27.02.2018
05.11.2018
22.05.2018
01.11.2018
01.08.2018
01.08.2018
16.10.2018
22.08.2018
21.11.2018
```

so as you can see, I imported a table from a csv file. I only need to see dates before today (16.10.2018), but when I run the code this is what I get

```
Column 1    
05.11.2018  
01.11.2018  
01.08.2018
01.08.2018
```

Which means Python is only looking at the days and ignoring the months, and this is wrong. I need it to understand this is a date not just numbers. What do I do to achieve that?

PS I'm new to Python

Comment: It considers the items to be *strings*.

Comment: `pd.Timestamp("today").strftime(%d.%m.%y)` isn't valid. I also suspect it doesn't work in place. Use `to_datetime`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Apologies if I sounded too simple, I'm very new to Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your column to the *date* type, not strings, since strings are compared lexicographically.

You can thus convert it with:

```
# convert the strings to date(time) objects
df['column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column1'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Then you can compare it with a `date` object, like:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> df[df['column1'] < date.today()]
     column1
0 2018-02-27
1 2018-05-11
2 2018-05-22
3 2018-01-11
4 2018-01-08
5 2018-01-08
7 2018-08-22
```

Comment: Much appreciated!